# PDO::FETCH_COLUMN returning less rows than PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple query that returns all ISBN's from an inventory table in my database, in total there should be around 6650 results returned but for some reason PDO::FETCH_COLUMN is short changing me returning only 4851 results, below are the two different functions i use for retrieving data with pdo mysql

**functions in php**

```
/* returns all select results in multi-dimensional arrays */
public function select($query){ 
    try{
        $stmt = $this->dbh->query($query);
        $arr = array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
        return $arr;

    }catch(PDOException $e){  
        echo "Error with select_array function: ".$e->getMessage();  
    }
}

/* returns only one column in one array, used when selecting one column */
public function select_one_column($query){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->dbh->query($query);
        $arr = array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)){
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
        return $arr;

    }catch(PDOException $e){  
        echo "Error with select_array function: ".$e->getMessage();  
    }
}
```

**example use**

```
$query = "select isbn from inventory";
print_r($this->select($query));
array(
   [0] => Array
      (
         [isbn] => 1843060469
      )
   [1] => Array
      (
         [isbn] => 184306152X
      )
)

print_r($this->select_one_colum($query));
array(
    [0] => 1843060469
    [1] => 184306152X
)
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Something else.  The first two results don't even appear in the second four results.

Comment: these are just example results, ill change that to clarify things